# Ho do I get a list from compounded names with strange characters in python?

Tags: python, regex

How can I generate a list with regex in python for countries with compounded names?

```
names = ['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Cần Thơ', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung', 'Benin City', 'Ciudad Nezahualcóyotl', 'Biên Hòa', 'São Gonçalo', 'São Luís', 'New Orleans', 'Thủ Đức']
```

I was trying to do this but it returns all names:

```
import re

lst = []
for word in names:
    if re.findall(r'[A-Z]\w+\b', word[0]) == re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w+', word[1]):
        lst.append(word)

print(lst)

Output:
['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Cần Thơ', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung', 'Benin City', 'Ciudad Nezahualcóyotl', 'Biên Hòa', 'São Gonçalo', 'São Luís', 'New Orleans', 'Thủ Đức']
```

The desired output would be [Ba Beja, Bandar Bampung].

It is an exercise that's why I can only do it with the module re. Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: what's your definition of a compounded name?

Comment: Names with two words, in this case.

Comment: countries and cities ?? or only countries?

Comment: Any of them, the output I'm looking for is [ Ba Beja, Bandar Bampung] , meaning that get elements if they have the same letter at the beginning of each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so I have **two answers** for you.
One that uses REGEX, and the other that doesn't.

**Here is the REGEX version:**

```py
import re

names = ['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Cần Thơ', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung', 'Benin City', 'Ciudad Nezahualcóyotl', 'Biên Hòa', 'São Gonçalo', 'São Luís', 'New Orleans', 'Thủ Đức']

pattern = re.compile(r'^([A-zÀ-ứ])[A-zÀ-ứ]*\s\1[A-zÀ-ứ]*$')

lst = []
for line in names:
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        lst.append(line)

print(lst)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung']
```

---

**And here is the other answer that does not use Regex:**

```py
names = ['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Cần Thơ', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung', 'Benin City', 'Ciudad Nezahualcóyotl', 'Biên Hòa', 'São Gonçalo', 'São Luís', 'New Orleans', 'Thủ Đức']

lst = []
space = ' '
for line in names:
    if space in line: 
        first, second = line.split(space)
        if first[0] == second[0]:
            lst.append(line)
            
print(lst)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Nizhniy Novgorod', 'Ba Beja', 'Bandar Bampung']
```